# cat without line breaks: why does tr '\n' not work?

Tags: linux, bash

I generated 1000 output files containing a single line with (mistakenly) no line break at the end, so that

```
cat filnename_* > outfile
```

generates a file with a single line. I attempted to remedy this using

```
cat filename_* | tr '\n' ' ' > outfile
```

but I get exactly the same result - a file with a single line of output. Why doesn't the latter code (which ought to add a line break for each filename_* file) accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Is there some straightforward way to introduce a '\n' at the end of each line (file) in cat so that I will get an output file with 1000 lines from each?

Comment: Is there a way to do this within cat?

Comment: only thing I can think of would be a custom function; see 2nd half of my answer

Comment: You can intersperse the filenames on the command line with a name that, when read, returns only a single newline. Is that "within cat" for your purposes?

Comment: To be clear, if your input files were in valid UNIX text format none of this would be necessary, because all lines in UNIX _including_ the last one are required to have training newlines for the file to be considered text by the letter of the standard. So there's no reason for `cat` to include special functionality for this; if it's given correctly formed input the problem never happens.

Comment: `perl -ne 'print; print "\n" if( eof)'  filename_*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your files are missing the final linefeed then you can use `sed` for adding it on the fly:

```bash
# with GNU sed
sed '$s/$/\n/' filnename_* > outfile

# with standard sed and bash, zsh, etc...
sed $'$s/$/\\\n/' filnename_* > outfile

# with standard sed and a POSIX shell
sed '$s/$/\
/' filnename_* > outfile
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could manually append a line break to your 1000 out files, and then `cat` them all later:

```bash
echo | tee -a filename_*
cat filnename_* > outfile
```

Edit:
Change the first step to `echo | tee -a filename_*` as @rowboat suggested

Comment: `echo` emits a single line break called with no arguments at all. `echo -e '\n'` emits two if you're lucky, or the string `-e` followed by a space and then a newline if you're unlucky. (Read the APPLICATION USAGE section of the POSIX spec for `echo` for context; bash has several different ways its copy of echo can be configured at either compile time or runtime to let it comply with that standard)

Answer (score 1):

`tr '\n' ' '` says to replace each `\n` with a space; you've already stated the inputs do not contain any `\n` so the `tr` does nothing and the final output is just a copy of the input

Setup:

```
for ((i=1;i<=5;i++))
do
    printf 'abcd' > out${i}
done

$ cat out*
abcdabcdabcdabcdabcd
```

Many commands can process a file and add a `\n`, it just depends on how much typing you want to do, eg:

```
$ sed 's/$/&/' out*      # or: sed -n '/$/p' out*
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd

$ awk '1' out*
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
```

---

I'm not coming up with any ideas on how to use `cat` to append a `\n` but one idea would be to use a user-defined function; assume we want to name our new function `catn` (`cat` and add `\n` on end):

```
$ type -a catn                           # verify name "catn" not currently in use
-bash: type: catn: not found

$ catn() { awk '1' "${@:--}"; }          # wrap function definition around the awk solution

$ catn out*  
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
```